# removing entire rows to make the two datasets the same size

Tags: r, row

I need help removing the rows for which the elements in the first column (V1) do not correspond to those in the column (X1). My dataset is much larger, I just used this example to make it easier to understand.

```
         V1   V2   V3            X1  X2  X3
 [1,]     1    2    3     [1,]    1   2   3
 [2,]     2    2    3     [2,]    1   2   3
 [3,]     1    2    3     [3,]    1   2   3
 [4,]     1    2    3
 [5,]     3    2    3
```

For this example I would require the code to remove the rows [2,] and [5,] as they are different from what you have in X1 (The general idea is to fix my dataset so they have the same elements and remove those that are in V but not in X).

The code I thought is this:

```
for(k in 1:nrow(V)){
    if(V[k,1]!=X[k,1]){
       V[-k,]
    }
 }
```

but it does not work because the size for V is different than X.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: You seem to compare only `V1` and `X1` in your example and @akrun 's answer is the most efficient way to do this. However, you also mention "...that are in V but not in X". What happens if your first table has a row like 1,2,2 ? Do you want to remove that? You don't expect cases like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to get the logical index of elements of 'V1' (in matrix 'm1') that is present in 'X1' (from 'm2'), negate (`!`) to get elements not present, and use that as row index to subset the 'm1'.

```
m1[!m1[,'V1'] %in% m2[, 'X1'],]
#     V1 V2 V3
#[1,]  2  2  3
#[2,]  3  2  3
```